# How to store the data in the dataframes in Pyspark

Tags: python, dataframe, pyspark

I am new in Pyspark and trying to figure out how to store the data in dataframe. I have the table of size `n x 8`, where `n` is very large.
Lets say `df` has `x1`, `x2`, `x3`, `x4`, `x5`, `x6`, `x7`, `x8` columns.

4 of 8 columns remain constant in the cycle (`x1`, `x2`, `x3`, `x4`) and 4 columns change (`x5`, `x6`, `x7`, `x8`).

```
for i in range(1, iterations):
   df = df.alias("L").join(df_second.alias("R"), (df.x1 == df_second.x1), how="left")\
        .select("L.*", sum(col("w")*col("x7")).over(Window.partitionBy("x1")).alias("x8"))\
        .distinct()\
        .sort('x1')
   df = df.withColumn("x5", col('x6'))
   df = df.withColumn("x6", col('x5') - col("x1")*(col("x3") - col("x4")))
   df = df.withColumn("x6", when(df.sampled > 0, df.x2).otherwise(df.x6))
   df = df.withColumn("x7", 2*col('x6') - col("x5")*col("x8"))
```

This works slower with every iteration and with n larger than `50000` I am having memory issues. I made research and find out about `cache` and `persist` function, but can not figure out how to use those in a right way.

My questions are following:

1. Should I store the constant columns and changing columns in different dataframes (`df1` and `df2` respectively)? If so should I use `d1.persist`?
2. What will happen if I will do `df = df.cache()` and will overwrite cached `df` with the operation like `df = df.withColumn("x5", col('x6'))`? Will `df` still be cached or should I somehow clean `df` first from the memory and do `df = df.withColumn("x5", col('x6')).cache()` later?
3. How to make spark split data for pieces and work with those so that I will not run out of the memory?
4. I tried to force to calculate lazy transformations by calling
   `df = sc.parallelize(df.collect()).toDF().cache()` which slowed down the program very much but every iteration requires almost the same amount of time. Is there any correct way for doing it? Checkpoints made it even slower.

Comment: This could help [to save tables as temporary in memory](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/python/pyspark.sql.html#pyspark.sql.DataFrame.registerTempTable) and this [to unpersist](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/python/pyspark.sql.html#pyspark.sql.DataFrame.unpersist) dataframes. A new dataframe is created when you make a change inside `for` block. So, maybe, save it, unpersist and read help

Comment: @Gocht Thank you very much! It looks like something I was looking for!

Answer (score 0):

@Gocht's solution is probably better. But here is another way to force the computation and persistance.

```
def cache_on_parquet(df):
    TEMP = 'temp.parquet'
    df.write.parquet(TEMP, mode='overwrite')
    return sqlc.read.parquet(TEMP)
```

After one or some iterations

```
df = cache_on_parquet(df)
```